# How to evaluate a line integral on a curve?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, line-integrals

How do I calculate this line integral? The answer to this porblem is 61/6 here but I am not very confident in line integration. My attempt is below the problem.

---

**Problem:**
[image]

---

**Attempt:**
$$ \int_CB \cdot dl = \int_C (-x^2,y,3) \cdot (dx,dy,dz) = $$
$$ = \int_C -x^2 dx + \int_C y dy + \int_C 3 dz = \int_0^1 -x^2 dx + \int_2^5 y dy + \int_5^5 3 dz  $$

So the last term (involving z) is 0. But what is the strategy for the two first terms? I am trying to rewrite the functions using $y=3x^2+2$.

For the first term:
$$y=3x^2+2 \longrightarrow x^2 = (y-2)/3 \longrightarrow dx = ?$$
$x$ from 0 to 1 on C given by:
$$\int_0^1 -x^2 dx = \int_0^1 -\frac{(y-2)}{3} dx $$

For the second term:
y from 2 to 5 on C given by:
$$y=3x^2+2 \longrightarrow dy = dx 6x$$
$$\int_2^5 y dy = \int_2^5 6x dx $$

What I am unsure about is the limits of integration (if it should be from 0 to 1 when I have dx in 2nd term and how to get the differential line element dx (like if you can get it from same function $y=3x^2+2$ or need to derive $x^2 = (y-2)/3 \longrightarrow dx = ?$.

Comment: Your vector field is conservative. In fact, $(-x^2,y,3)=\vec{\nabla}f$ where $f(x,y,z)=-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{y^2}{2}+3z$. By the fundemantal theorem of line integrals, $$\int_C B \cdot \mathrm{d}l=f(1,5,5)-f(0,2,5)=\frac{61}{6}$$ Also, as a general rule, you cannot split up line integrals in the manner you demonstrate in your post. For example, if $F=(y,x)$ and $C$ is the portion of $y=x^2$ joining $(-1,1)$ and $(2,4)$ oriented from left to right, how would you compute $\int_C F \cdot \mathrm{d}r$?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you should parameterize the path of integration, and rewrite the integral so you are integrating with respect to that parameter. So the path $C$ is parameterized as
$$(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (t, 3t^2+2, 5), 0\leq t \leq 1$$
and you have $$B = (-x(t)^2, y(t), 3) = (-t^2, 3t^2+2, 3)$$
$$dl = (x'(t)dt, y'(t)dt, z'(t)dt) = (1, 6t, 0)\, dt$$
so $$ B\cdot dl = (18t^3 - t^2 + 12t)\, dt$$
and
$$\int_C B\cdot dl = \int_{t=0}^1(18t^3 - t^2 + 12t)\, dt$$
$$=\left(\tfrac92t^4 - \tfrac13t^3 + 6t^2\right)\Biggr\rvert_{t=0}^1$$
$$= \tfrac92 - \tfrac13 + 6 = \tfrac{61}{6}$$

*[Note: I corrected the minus sign I missed in the first component of $B$ in my original post]*